# An Pixel XL phone shutdown by itself

Tags: logging, google-pixel, shutdown

My Pixel XL phone rencently always turns off by itself. Most times it turned off just after starting up, a few times it worked longer and everything looks fine. when it happend, a "phone is shuting down"(maybe not exactly these words because my phone is not in english) dialog pop up and then shut down in a few seconds.

I tried restoring it to factory image, and tried replace a new battery, and had not fix this.

I got the log using "adb logcat", here is it : [full log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXuEhoeCIP3n8droPx57jgnuSUR_FzH0/view)

Now I think its because of a hardware part, but seems not battery. I want to find out which hardware part is it from the log file, but I don't know much about the log messages, can anyone help to find some clues about what cause the auto-shutdown? Thank you very much!

John.

Comment: How do you know it is not the battery? Does the problem still occur when the charger is connected?

Comment: The log only shows that the system itself (uid 1000) has initiated a shutdown via ActivityManager and android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN. There is no visible reason. May be you should retry using `adb logcat -b all`.

Comment: I had replaced the battery with new one before, and did not change anything.  And yes it occurs no matter the charger connected or not. Thank you for your suggestion and I will try to get more log today.

Comment: I got a new log file using "adb logcat -b all", here is it : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jgc2pCZSxPmkrc9bCIy5Di-2zYsGubZX) . Some error messages about battery appears, but currently it's the new battery in use. Can you get more details? Thanks!

Comment: If I interpret the line `battery l=63 v=3913 t=72.7 h=3 st=2 c=5 chg=u` correctly the `h=3` means battery health status `BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT`. And `t=72.7` should be the temperature but don't ask me if this is Celsius or Fahrenheit. This could be an explanation for the forced shutdown.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I know why it keeps shutdown itself! The temperature of my room is about 20 degrees Celsius, so looks like the phone get the value in Fahrenheit but think it's in Celsius, but it's another question. I think you completely answered my question, could you make a answer so I can accepy it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided logcat it seems like the shutdown is initiated by the `healthd` that manages for example the battery status:

```
healthd : battery l=63 v=3913 t=72.7 h=3 st=2 c=5 chg=u
```

This line contains two values of interest:

1. `h=3` is the battery health value and the value 3 means [BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT).
2. `t=72.7` is the battery temperature in Celsius. This value is quite high taking it as temperature in Celsius as Android does. Hence I would assume that the battery provides the temperature in Fahrenheit but the device expects a Celsius value and therefore thinks that the battery temperature is very high. The default shutdown temperature in Android is 68°C.

What I not really understand is that all healthd message contain the `h=3` value even if the temperature is lower. May be this value also reflects past temperature states.

Note: Internally Android does not directly use the temperature in Celsius, instead it uses   Centigrade (Celsius * 10).

At the moment I would recommend to do the following test: Pack your phone into a water proof box and place it for some minutes in he refrigerator (make sure you use the part that has more than 0°C, you just want to cool down the device not freeze it!).
Then get it out of the fridge and start it, and measure the run-time until it shuts down. The time should be larger than before.

Comment: Thanks for these info! I'll follow your suggestion and try more.